# Flash actionscript 3 game performance - removing objects and resetting properties

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, object, cpu

I am working on a flash game that requires me to instantiate objects from a class into the scene at runtime and and delete these objects through code.
This works fine and i can dynamically add and remove instances from the game, however after about two minutes in it starts lagging extremely and will eventually crash alltogether.

I used `numchildren()` to trace how many objects are in the scene and it appears that some of the instances aren't being deleted properly because the number traced will increase and eventually reach near 2000 objects...

I am using `removeChild()` to delete the objects and am trying to figure out why these objects are still in the scene. 
I read somewhere that objects may still use cpu if they haven't properly been reset.

I am still new to working in flash and my main question is - how do I find out which objects aren't being deleted and how do I remove them entirely from the game?

What else do I need to add to the code other than the simple `removeChild()` part?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide the code part where removeChild() method is used.

Generally you should use removeChild() this way:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var movieClip:MovieClip;
var timer:Timer=new Timer(5000, 1);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);

makeMovieClips();

function makeMovieClips() {
    for (var i:int; i<2000; i++) {
        movieClip=new MovieClip();
        movieClip.graphics.beginFill(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF);
        movieClip.graphics.drawCircle(Math.random()*stage.stageWidth, Math.random()*stage.stageHeight, Math.random()*40);
        movieClip.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(movieClip);
    }
    trace (numChildren) // should output 2000;
    timer.start();
}

function onTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void {
    while (numChildren>0) {
        movieClip=getChildAt(0) as MovieClip;
        removeChild(movieClip);
        // or we can use removeChildAt(0); instead of 2 lines above
    }
    trace (numChildren) // should output 0, because all objects are removed from display list;
}
```

additionally note that removing objects form display list, won't exclude them from memory, if any references are left on those objects. In my example reference to one MovieClip object remains after all Movieclips are removed from stage, so it will occupy some portion of VM's memory and Garbage Collector won't clean that portion. In my example, to remove reference, I should add this line of code after while loop in onTimerComplete method:

```
movieClip=null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have now found the cause for all the undeleted objects through debugging using this.contains() to see if certain objects are still in the scene and it turns out I had simply forgotten to add the removeChild() statement in another part of my code. However, the second part of your answer is really useful to know - deleting the reference.. In my code I had been keeping an array of all the objects I instantiated and that is how I referenced them. Following your example of movieClip=null; I have set the array reference to null after deleting the instance.